# Data not getting fetched using aggregation query in nodejs

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, collections, aggregation-framework

I tried below code but only first match is checked and displayed,others displayed as object, why I am unable to see it in console. I have 3 collections student subject teacher, also made schema for the same. tried aggregation

```
Student.aggregate([

            {

              $match: { name: 'abcd'}
            },

            {
            $lookup:
             {
               from:'teachers',
               pipeline: [{ $match: { name: 'pqrs' } },],
               as: "teacherLookup"

             }
            },
            {
            $lookup:
             {
               from:'subjects',
               pipeline: [{ $match: { name: 'computer' } }],
               as: "subjectLookup"
             }
            }

          ]).then(function (res) {
            console.log(res); 
            res.forEach(function(students){
              let id = students._id;
              console.log(id+ ' got id ')

            }

    output
    student 
    name:'abcd' -- its fetched and other two not displaying values only shows object
    teacherLookup: [ [Object] ]
    subjectLookup: [ [Object] ]
```

Comment: Yes, because lookup generates the array output. You need to iterate over it to log.

Comment: how to specifically fetch only the  _id from db with the name given.

Comment: {
            $lookup:
             {
               from:'teachers',
               pipeline: [aggregation{{ $match: { name: 'pqrs' } },{_id:'1'}} ],
               as: "teacherLookup"

             }
            },

Comment: tried above but met error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were there just to project something you have to use `$project` stage.

Here I'm adding the query:

```
Student.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { name: 'abcd'}
  },
  {
    $lookup:{
       from:'teachers',
       pipeline: [
        { 
          $match: { name: 'pqrs' } 
        },
        {
          $project:{
            "_id":1
          }
        }
       ],
       as: "teacherLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup:
     {
       from:'subjects',
       pipeline: [
        { 
          $match: { name: 'computer' } 
        },
        {
          $project:{
            "_id":1
          }
        }
       ],
       as: "subjectLookup"
     }
  }
])
```

For more about `$project` refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).

Hope this will help :)